# Can I have multiple link relations with the same URI in HATEOAS?

Tags: hateoas

I have a resource, in this case:

```
http://www.domain.com/sales-rep/{id}
```

Each sales representative has multiple products which they can sell.  The URI for this resource would be:

```
http://www.domain.com/sales-rep/{id}/products
```

The problem is, depending on a user's permissions, you might be able to only `GET` or `GET` and `PUT` against this resource.

My problem is designing link relations when retrieving the sales rep resource.  For example my JSON could look as follows:

```
{ 
  firstname : "Dave",
  lastname : "Matthews",
  links : [ 
    { rel : "self", href : "http://www.domain.com/sales-rep/dmat1" },
    { rel : "products", href : "http://www.domain.com/sales-rep/dmat1/products" }
  ] 
}
```

If I take this approach, my link relation is well named as a noun representing the resource.  However it doesn't communicate to the client whether I can edit the resource or not.  As far as I'm aware HTTP methods in links are not part of the spec & these are the responsibility of the documentation, so how do I communicate the permissions?

```
    { 
      firstname : "Dave",
      lastname : "Matthews",
      links : [ 
        { rel : "self", href : "http://www.domain.com/sales-rep/dmat1" },
        { rel : "view-products", href : "http://www.domain.com/sales-rep/dmat1/products",
        { rel : "edit-products", href : "http://www.domain.com/sales-rep/dmat1/products" }
      ] 
    }
```

Something like that could work, making it easy for the client to create a menu with the correct links based on the presence of the `edit-products` rel.  The curies for the two different rels would then link to different sections in the documentation, one for `GET` and `PUT` respectively.  But does this make sense?  Both approaches feel wrong to me.

Answer (score 2):

short answer is yes, having the same URL behind different links comes up quite often.  But what you worried about has no simple answer, it's completely based on your desired UX.

Note that view-products & edit-products are not registered link relations (see http://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml ) for the list, so they should actually be URI's.

This is important because it's very common to let those URI's be dereferenceable/hence URLs which actually contain documentation about what the link relationship means.  Thus your edit-products turned into a URL eg http://example.com/rels/edit-products and retrieved could result in documentation indicating what can be edited.

But i would find an edit link at this level to be rather strange.  Generally there's a few things you could edit here, the product collection and the individual products in the collection.  Let's focus on the latter first.

Each product is presumably a resource, so it has it's own self link.  If i want to change that product as a developer it'd be natural for me to PUT some JSON representing a product to the self link.  I don't need an edit link because my intent is clear with my request.  If i'm unable to edit, then i should get a response indicating this (and if it's over http the appropriate http response code).  If i want to remove that product I could send a DELETE to the URL of the self link. If i wanted to modify the product specifically i might use a PATCH request.  If you want more restrained editing capabilities, then the edit-form IANA link relationship would be a good candidate, following this would return a form used to edit the resource as the service intends/allows.  And again you could have your own URI relationship that follows whatever conventions you document.  The other consideration you seem to have is you want the client to know if it can or cannot edit the resource.  If you do the edit-form case then it's as easy as having or not having that relationship present.  You can also use the edit IANA relationship to indicate raw editing capabilities (and it could have the same URL as self).

So i think that covers products, let's talk about the collection.

The ideas behind editing the collection are the same even if you've decided that each product isn't it's own resource.  A PUT of a product to the collection's self url would imply adding a product to the collection, while a PUT of a product collection to the self url would replace the entire collection.  PATCH would modify the collection.  On top of that if you had interesting cases where a user could only add a product, but not remove or reorder them, than I would start dipping into custom link relationships.   Again the presence of relationships could indicate to the client what can and cannot be done if you need such functionality.

I might question why you have a products collection resource at all.  Instead why not have product links off of the sales rep:

```
{ 
  firstname : "Dave",
  lastname : "Matthews",
  links : [ 
    { rel : "self", href : "http://www.domain.com/sales-rep/dmat1" },
    { rel : "product", href : "http://www.domain.com/product1" },
    { rel : "product", href : "http://www.domain.com/product2" },
    { rel : "product", href : "http://www.domain.com/product3" },
    { rel : "product", href : "http://www.domain.com/product4" }
  ] 
}
```

Again i don't know your whole model and UX, but this would let you edit the sales rep resource to add or remove products, while products stand alone as their own resources.

Something that isn't quite clear is if you intend edit-products to return a resource used for editing the products (like a form).  I often find it very useful to think of my JSON api just as i would my HTML application (web site) as web sites are very RESTful in nature.  In an HTML driven application this would probably be the case.  IE on the sales rep page (resource) you'd have a link to a page (resource) that allows the user to edit their products.  ditto viewing products.  In such a case these view product and edit products pages may be the same resource (IE it's the same page that lets you view and edit), or different resources (IE two different pages one just for editing, one just for viewing).   In the former they'd probably have the same URL and in the latter they'd have different URLs.  What's so cool about RESTful is that your app can change without it's semantics changing.  At first you might want them to be separate pages, one for viewing one for editing, so they are different URLs, but then you might change your mind and decide one page for doing both is appropriate.  now the two link relationships have the same URL but any UI built on top of these relationships still functions correctly and transitions the user to the desired resource.

There's another other option (pun) that you have and that's to submit an OPTIONS request to the self url.  This should give the http methods available to the requesting user, such as PATCH, PUT, POST, DELETE, etc.  from this collection of options you can construct a UI providing the right UI controls.  This is unfortunately requires an extra roundtrip to the server, but is a very nice mechanism to determine the current client's allowed capabilities.

With this i bring up the most important point.  In general the request method (and the request as a whole) implies the intent of the client (update, delete, add, reset, patch, whatever) and the service should interpret that intent (as well as document possible intents) and decide to fulfill the request or not.  With this approach and an OPTIONS request you should generally not need to have anything but the SELF link an hierarchy relationships (eg: products) for a simple CRUD application

Comment: Am a bit lost on edit-form rel link.  This implies I should make a resource called /sales-rep/bob/products/edit-form - Not sure what an edit-form should look like exactly?  A PUT to /products feels better but I might be missing something?

Comment: an html form is a great target resource for an edit form.  There's other standards for forms.

Comment: While I agree with most of the post, I have serious issues with 2 points listed here. First, you assume that a client already knows what a server expects as input (tight coupling?!), hence you can directly use `PUT`, `POST`, ... on a certain endpoint instead of requesting a resource that teaches you what a server needs. `edit-form` does exactly this. The second concern I have is with this sentence: `A PUT of a product to the collection's self url would imply adding a product to the collection` Really? According to RFC 7231 it should replace the content of the collection with the product data

Comment: you say edit-form i say use the link relationship URL to retrieve some information about how to construct the thing...or a profile link.  but yeah sure edit-form works too, just not my preference.  as to the put... if you PUT a collection to the collection href it'd replace the collection, but if you PUT a product to the collection href, i think the intent is to add the product.  But i'd have that all described in the rel docs.  You could also just fail saying hey, i expect you to put a collection, i don't know what to do with just a product! but i like to make my services more forgiving